# Set up theme after Magento 2 composer install

Tags: magento2, theme, composer

Sorry, but all the doc I found are referring to classic Magento 2 install.

The composer installation gives a different Magento file system, so theme tutorials looks useless.

I have tried a lot of hacks, including renaming default Luma theme, having changed of course `theme.xml` and `registration.php` settings, but at now it is impossible to have the new theme listed in admin panel.

Comment: You can explain more about the way you create new custom theme?

Comment: mv  theme-frontend-luma theme-frontend-mytheme

then edit

theme.xml
register.php

replacing 'luma' with 'mytheme'

Comment: You should try http://www.boolfly.com/create-new-magento-2-theme/ and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Comment: No, sorry, but that's the issue: when you install Magento with Composer the file system is different: you haven't a  app/design/<Vendor> directory rather that vendor/magento/theme-themename.
All the tutorials are about the first type of filesystem...

Comment: [Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html) is how the theme should look under `vendor`.

Answer (score 1):

The Luma and Blank theme are located under the vendor directory, you want to create your theme in the app/design/frontend directory. The [official dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) do a good job of explaining how to set up a theme.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking in the wrong place. They moved where the theme is SELECTED.

As for installing a theme:

/app/design/frontend/THEMEVENDOR/THEMENAME

Create the design directory if it doesn't exist - it will work.